# Android New Version Available - App Update Dialog Using Json From Own Server

Tags: android-dialog, jsonparser, android-app-indexing, jsondecoder, app-update

I want to show dialogue when *new version* is available.

I want to make a json file into my web server, and I will manually update my app version in json file. and my app will *parse* this json file and will notify users and showing **dialogue box** to update my app from playstore link by clicking **Update** button.

I don't want to make this with **firebase**.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ForceUpdateAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{

private String latestVersion;
private String currentVersion;
private Context context;
public ForceUpdateAsync(String currentVersion, Context context){
    this.currentVersion = currentVersion;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    try 
 {
         latestVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+context.getPackageName()+"&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get()
                .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                .first()
                 .ownText();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new JSONObject();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if(latestVersion!=null){
        if(!currentVersion.equalsIgnoreCase(latestVersion)){
           // Toast.makeText(context,"update is available.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(!(context instanceof SplashActivity)) {
                if(!((Activity)context).isFinishing()){
                    showForceUpdateDialog();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
}

public void showForceUpdateDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context,
            R.style.DialogDark));

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.youAreNotUpdatedTitle));
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.youAreNotUpdatedMessage) + " " + latestVersion + context.getString(R.string.youAreNotUpdatedMessage1));
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.update, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName())));
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.show();
}
 }
```

after that in your splash activity just use this code

```
 public void forceUpdate()
{
    PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
    try {
        packageInfo =  packageManager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String currentVersion = packageInfo.versionName;
    new ForceUpdateAsync(currentVersion,BaseActivity.this).execute();
}
```

Comment: it's not working. i'm created ForceUpdateAsync.java and insert the above code, and i was put this below code to mainactivity. all string are created, but it still not showing the update dialogue. need to do anything on Minifests file? please help.

Comment: my main activity contain with 3 different fragment. where actually need to place this 2nd code? i'm placed this to main activity.

Comment: just add this in splash activity and make them in if contidition

Comment: not working bro... can you tell me clearly about how to do this step by step in short?

Comment: do i need to implements? and how to?